# Backing up a single file in Azure website

Tags: azure, backup, azure-web-app-service

I have a website in Azure which uses a SQL CE 4.0 database. For security reasons, I want to have a backup of the database created daily and stored for two weeks.

The database is fairly small (under 10 MB), but the website itself contains a huge folder with images, which can be up to 1 GB. The images are never modified and I want to avoid redundantly backing them up.

What is the optimal way to set up backup for such a case?

Comment: Do you want to back up the website and images too, or just the database?

Comment: @BenV, only the database. I updated the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a list of files and folders to exclude from your backups by listing them in a _backup.filter file.

In your case it sounds like you want to exclude everything, so you would want to specify the root folder as the folder you want to exclude

Full details are here:
http://www.zainrizvi.io/2015/06/05/creating-partial-backups-of-your-site-with-azure-web-apps/